# How to get the beginning of the day in POSIXct

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

My day starts at `2016-03-02 00:00:00`. Not `2016-03-02 00:00:01`.

How do I get the beginning of the day in `POSIXct` in local time?

My confusing probably comes from the fact that R sees this as the end-date of 2016-03-01? Given that R uses an ISO 8601?

For example if I try to find the beginning of the day using Sys.Date():

```
as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), tz = "CET")
"2016-03-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

Which is not correct - but are there other ways?

I know I can hack my way out using a simple

```
as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), "00:00:00", sep = " "), tz = "CET")
```

But there has to be a more correct way to do this? Base R preferred.

Comment: added tz, just to be clear - they are not the problem. The problem is that R counts 00:00:00 to the previous day, not the current.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a single command---but you want `as.POSIXlt()`:

```
R> as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())
[1] "2016-03-02 UTC"
R> format(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2016-03-02 00:00:00"
R>
```

It is only when converting to `POSIXct` happens that the timezone offset to UTC (six hours for me) enters:

```
R> as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())
[1] "2016-03-01 18:00:00 CST"
R>
```

Needless to say by wrapping both you get the desired *type* and *value*:

```
R> as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()))
[1] "2016-03-02 UTC"
R>
```

*Filed under once again no need for lubridate or other non-Base R packages.*

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding that you understandably prefer base R, a "smart way," for certain meaning of "smart," would be:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- floor_date(Sys.Date(),"day")

> format(x,"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
[1] "2016-03-02-00-00-00"
```

From `?floor_date`:

> floor_date takes a date-time object and rounds it down to the nearest
>   integer value of the specified time unit.

Pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit unclear.

You are talking about a 1 minute difference for the day start, but your example shows a 1 hour difference due to the timezone.

You can try

```
?POSIXct
```

to get the functionality explained.

Using Sys.Date() withing POSIXct somehow overwrites your timezone setting.

```
as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), tz="EET")  
 "2016-03-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

While entering a string gives you

```
as.POSIXct("2016-03-01 00:00:00", tz="EET")  
 "2016-03-01 EET"
```

It looks like 00:00:00 is actually the beginning of the day. You can conclude it from the results of the following 2 inequalities

```
as.POSIXct("2016-03-02 00:00:02 CET")>as.POSIXct("2016-03-02 00:00:01 CET")
```

TRUE

```
as.POSIXct("2016-03-02 00:00:01 CET")>as.POSIXct("2016-03-02 00:00:00 CET")
```

TRUE

So somehow this is a timezone issue. Notice that 00:00:00 is automatically removed from the as.POSIXct result.

```
as.POSIXct("2016-03-02 00:00:00 CET")
```

"2016-03-02 CET"

Comment: No, `POSIXct` has a timezone attribute. It's not always in UTC. One just has to take care to use the `tz` parameter of `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: You are right, but that is not what I am saying. Apparently the internal representation is in seconds since 1-1-1970 (UTC timezone). 
Wouldn't that  mean that the beginning of the new day starts at 00:00:00 UTC? That would explain Lasse's observation.

Comment: Edited my original answer and removed most of the UTC references since the underlying issue seems to be with Sys.Date() in combination with as.POSIXct and **not** with UTC.

Comment: Conversion from `Date` to `POSIXct` is done via `POSIXlt`. Try `as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date(), tz="EET"), tz="EET")`.

Comment: You're right that works. However the innermost timezone is unnecessary since Sys.Date() somehow overwrites the timezone.

Comment: `Sys.Date` returns a `Date`. Timezones are not a concept relevant for dates.

Comment: Not really an answer? I didn't know Sys.Date() didn't have a time zone component, nor did I actually assume it did - but I still need to find the beginning of the day in a smart way.

Comment: Thanks. What Roland posted yesterday works on my machine, so without the inner timezone and for CET that would become  

    'as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()), tz="CET")'