# R: changing timezone of an xts object after aggregation

Tags: r, datetime, time, aggregate, xts

I have a univariate time series object that I converted to an xts object in order to use the aggregatets() function. This is what it looks like:

```
> head(B, 20)
                    [,1]
2015-09-16 09:16:00    1
2015-09-16 09:16:26    1
2015-09-16 09:16:46    1
2015-09-16 09:17:28   -1
2015-09-16 09:19:17    1
2015-09-16 09:22:06   -1
```

The timezone is "IST"(Indian Standard Time) as it is correctly displayed above. When I run the aggregatets function on it, it changes the timezone to "GMT". I need it to stay in "IST" as I need to compare it other variables in the "IST" timezone. It also displays a warning message:

```
> C<- aggregatets(B, FUN = "sum")
> head(C, 20)
                    ts3
2015-09-16 03:47:00   3
2015-09-16 03:48:00  -1
2015-09-16 03:49:00  NA
2015-09-16 03:50:00   1
2015-09-16 03:51:00  NA
2015-09-16 03:52:00  NA
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone ().
```

I also tried manually changing the timezone through the indexTZ() function but that doesn't help either.

```
> indexTZ(C)<- "IST"
> head(C)
                    ts3
2015-09-16 03:47:00   3
2015-09-16 03:48:00  -1
2015-09-16 03:49:00  NA
2015-09-16 03:50:00   1
2015-09-16 03:51:00  NA
2015-09-16 03:52:00  NA
Warning message:
timezone of object (IST) is different than current timezone ().
```

I also tried changing the timezone selection in the aggregatets function itself to make a new function but it still spits out the same thing.

This is really weird because I have used this same method in some other variables I am trying to analyze but it doesn't give me the same problem.

Can someone please shed some light on if I'm missing something or how I should go about solving my problem and keeping the series in "IST"? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated and please let me know if you need any more information.

EDIT: Added as requested

```
whole_data<- read.csv(file = file,header = FALSE,sep = "", col.names = c("DateTime","Seq","BP1","BQ1","BO1","AP1","AQ1","AO1","BP2","BQ2","BO2","AP2","AQ2","AO2","BP3","BQ3","BO3","AP3","AQ3","AO3","BP4","BQ4","BO4","AP4","AQ4","AO4","BP5","BQ5","BO5","AP5","AQ5","AO5","BP6","BQ6","BO6","AP6","AQ6","AO6","BP7","BQ7","BO7","AP7","AQ7","AO7","BP8","BQ8","BO8","AP8","AQ8","AO8","BP9","BQ9","BO9","AP9","AQ9","AO9","BP10","BQ10","BO10","AP10","AQ10","AO10"), colClasses = c(NA, rep("integer",31), rep("NULL", 30)))
  whole_data<- whole_data[which(whole_data$DateTime != 0),]
  whole_data$DateTime= as.POSIXct(whole_data$DateTime/(10^9), origin="1970-01-01")

trades<- whole_data[!complete.cases(whole_data),]
          colnames(trades) <- c("DateTime", "Seq", "Price", "Qty", "TradeSide")
          trades[,5][trades[,5]==2]<- -1
          B<- as.xts(trades$TradeSide, order.by = trades$DateTime)
          C<- aggregatets(B, FUN = "sum", on = on, k = k)
```

The entire dataset is big. For this particular variable I only need the trade lines so I access by doing !complete.cases

I am still unable to solve this problem. Can you anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you define B? What is it data.frame? What are the 1 and -1 values in there? It looks like it's in the same column. Could it be timezone info?

Have a look at [How to get the beginning of the day in POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720154/how-to-get-the-beginning-of-the-day-in-posixct/35720430?noredirect=1#comment59153951_35720430) there are some timezone effects there too that are a surprise to me.

EDIT 20160309:
I think that using the origin without timezone causes it to use GMT. However I don't have time to try it.
Maybe you could try out the following code

```
whole_data$DateTime= as.POSIXct(whole_data$DateTime/(10^9), origin="1970-01-01", tz="IST")
```

Comment: Its definitely not in the same column and its not timezone info. B is a time series of buy and sell orders that I converted to an xts object from a data.frame.

Comment: Can you give the code you used to produce B and the underlying data frame? I get an as.POSIXlt.character conversion error when I try to convert a data.frame with your data to xts.

Comment: Posted code you requested. Sorry for the delay in response.

Comment: @UtdMan, I am afraid I have no time now. I hope I will be able to have a look on Friday.  
What surprises me though is that you divide DateTime by 10^9. It probably has nothing to do with your problem, but I am wondering why. Can you provide a sample value from the file for DateTime?  
See the edit in my answer. That might be your real problem.

Comment: I divide by 10^9 because my time stamps are in nanoseconds. The problem only arises when I aggregate the data and with nothing else

Comment: Ok, weird indeed. Can you as a work-around first convert to GMT and after the aggregation back to IST?

Comment: I am still unable to solve this problem. Anyone here, who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attr(index(C), "tzone") = "IST"`

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.